# Why does the תפילת הטבת חלום/רבונו prayer said during ברכת כהנים reference 5 seemingly random miracles

Tags: prayer-book, birchas-kohanim

Siddurim have a prayer called [תפילת הטבת חלום
/רבונו של עולם](https://wiki.jewishbooks.org.il/mediawiki/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%97_%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94/%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%A8_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D) in which we pray that bad dreams don't manifest in reality.
It references 5 seemingly random miracles. Two are cases of healing of צרעת (Miriam the prophetess, and le'havdil, a Syrian general named Na'aman) and two are cases of making water potable. What is the  connection between these specific miracles and bad dreams?

[Example from jewish books wiki](https://wiki.jewishbooks.org.il/mediawiki/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%97_%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94/%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%A8_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D):

> רִבּוֹנוֹ שֶׁל עוֹלָם. אֲנִי שֶׁלָּךְ וַחֲלוֹמוֹתַי שֶׁלָּךְ. חֲלוֹם חָלַמְתִּי וְאֵינִי יוֹדֵעַ מַה הוּא. יְהִי רָצוֹן מִלְּפָנֶיךָ יְהֹוָה אֱלֹהַי וֵאלֹהֵי אֲבוֹתַי. שֶׁיִּהְיוּ כָּל חֲלוֹמוֹתַי עָלַי וְעַל כָּל יִשְׂרָאֵל לְטוֹבָה. בֵּין שֶׁחָלַמְתִּי עַל עַצְמִי. וּבֵין שֶׁחָלַמְתִּי עַל אֲחֵרִים. וּבֵין שֶׁחָלְמוּ אֲחֵרִים עָלַי. אִם טוֹבִים הֵם חַזְּקֵם וְאַמְּצֵם וְיִתְקַיְּמוּ בִי וּבָהֶם כַּחֲלוֹמוֹתָיו שֶׁל יוֹסֵף הַצַּדִּיק. וְאִם צְרִיכִים רְפוּאָה רְפָאֵם, כְּחִזְקִיָּהוּ מֶלֶךְ יְהוּדָה מֵחָלְיוֹ, וּכְמִרְיָם הַנְּבִיאָה מִצָּרַעְתָּהּ, וּכְנַעֲמָן מִצָּרַעְתּוֹ, וּכְמֵי מָרָה עַל־יְדֵי משֶׁה רַבֵּנוּ, וּכְמֵי יְרִחוֹ עַל יְדֵי אֱלִישָׁע. וּכְשֵׁם שֶׁהָפַכְתָּ אֶת קִלְלַת בִּלְעָם הָרָשָׁע מִקְּלָלָה לִבְרָכָה כֵּן תַּהֲפוֹךְ כָּל חֲלוֹמוֹתַי עָלַי וְעַל כָּל יִשְׂרָאֵל לְטוֹבָה וְתִשְׁמְרֵנִי וּתְחָנֵּנִי וְתִרְצֵּנִי: אמן.

(P.S. According to [wikipedia](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%98%D7%91%D7%AA_%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D), the prayer comes from the Talmud, although the texts there doesn't have the Na'aman example.)

Comment: Presumably because they are all examples of a negative scenario being transformed into a positive one - which is what we want if we have had negative dreams?

Comment: The common demoniator seems to be the terminology רפואה

Comment: @chortkov2 That itself is bothering me, why is making water potable considered a רפואה?

Comment: @Dov but there are countless stories in tanach of bad scenarios turning in to good ones, why these?

Comment: @torahmike With Elisha the pasuk explicitly uses an expression of refuah (Melachim II:2:22). With Moshe there is also a link to refuah - the promise of כי אני ה' רופאיך (Shemos 15:26) immediately follows the epsiode of sweetening the water of Marah.

Comment: Volume 4, ch. 24 of the work יברכך השם (by אליעזר שלום רוטלוי) has several pages (pp. 453-458) exploring this specific topic. Unfortunately I don't have the time to summarize now, but I suggest looking there.